# Prove that if $(S_{n})_{n\in N}$ increases and $S_{n+1} - S_{n} \to 0$, then $S_{n}$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to prove that if $S(n)_{n\in N}$ increases and $S_{n+1} - S_{n} \to 0$, then $S_{n}$ is convergent (I came up with this proposition, so It may be false).

While it seems graphically obvious that the proposition is true, I couldn't write a correct proof of it.

Can you give me a hint on how to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac1i$ then it increases.

$S_{n+1}-S_n=\frac1{n+1} \to 0$ but $S_n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Still, I find this a little counter-intuitive. How can the difference between 2 consecutive terms of a series become infinitely close to 0, while still diverging to infinity? Is there a nice visual approach to understand this? (Thank you for your time)

Comment: @s89ne his example should provide you the intuition. It's because you keep adding $\frac{1}{n}$ to get from one term to the next. and $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges. That is, you add an infinite amount of space between the terms in total

Comment: @mathworker21 Thanks. then why does for example $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{2^k} \to 2$? In this case too, we keep on adding an infinite amount of space, don't we?

Comment: @s89ne no. because $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} < \infty$, we add a finite amount of space, namely, $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} = 2$

Comment: @mathworker21 I need some time to think more about this. Could we continue this conversation in private messages?

Comment: @s89ne I don't think private messages exist on this platform. How about you think this stuff over for a while and if you're still stuck, ask another question, and I'll respond.

Answer (score 1):

It is false. Just take $S_n=\sqrt n$ or $S_n=\log n$.